# Passing a return function in object pair with jQuery

Tags: jquery, object

so this plugin I'm working on, you can pass extra data in the setup of the plugin.

```
uploadData    : { 'extra_data' : 'blah' }
```

In the plugin, I have

```
 $.each(self.settings.uploadData, function(key, value)
 {
            console.log(key + ':' + value);
            data.append(key, value);
 });
```

The problem is it only accepts strings for **value**. But here's what I want to be able to pass as the value:

```
uploadData    : { folderName : function(){ return $('#folderName').val() } }
```

or

```
uploadData    : { folderName : $('#folderName').val() }
```

What ends up happening when I console log the value is I get the literal string of whatever is in place for value. How can I tell it to run the function if it is one?

Comment: Your latter logic should work, however note that `val()` always returns a string, so I'm not sure exactly what your issue is. Could you give a clearer example of the output you want to achieve.

Comment: Well there is an input field called folderName that is generated on blur of this Title field. Basically it strips spaces out and stores in this value. But regardless no matter which input field I use, the latter option returns NOTHING. The first returns the whole function.

Comment: BTW you can't hit submit to run this plugin unless the title field is filled in which means the blur would have happened and folderName would have a value. I DID check to see if it did before submit. But it's almost like this plugin is checking the folderName field at the init of the script and not when activated.

Comment: If I could play with it in a jsfiddle or something I could probably help you... but from only that it will change to string

Comment: Heres the plugin code. I confirmed that during that each loop under uploadFiles....its not checking the value again. It's going based off what is there when its first initiated. https://jsbin.com/vimudadulo/edit?js